# Select2 js - How to create a option when typing on search box

Tags: javascript, events, input, jquery-select2, onchange

I'm using select2 for create an unlimited option for select, which means whenever you type anything in select2 search box it can create an option related to what is the select for. Now I'm using the code below, which when type down it creates more than 1 option that I need it for.

Please help me with this.

```js
$('#form-label-category-exterior').select2({
        matcher: function matchExterior(params, data){
          if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
            return data;
          }
          if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
            return null;
          }
          if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
            var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
            return modifiedData;
          } else{
            var newOpt = new Option(params.term.toString() + '外装', params.term.toString() + '外装', true, true);
            $('#form-label-category-exterior').append(newOpt)
          }
          return null;
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the source of this feature from the link below. But as far as i understand you can only add an extra option here. So i think this is not what you want.

[Source Link](https://select2.org/tagging)

So i have different solution if you want to use. The code that i wrote
it creates new option and delete old option that my code created. I tried to explain everything. I hope that you get the point.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let oldValue = "";
  $('#form-label-category-exterior').select2({
    matcher: function matchExterior(params, data){
      if ($.trim(params.term) === '') return data;
      if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') return null;
      if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
        return $.extend({}, data, true);
      } else {
        const newText = params.term.toString() + '外装';
        var newOpt = new Option(newText, newText);
        $(`#form-label-category-exterior option[value="${oldValue}"]`).remove()
        $('#form-label-category-exterior').append(newOpt)
        const $return = data.id == params.term.slice(0, -1) + '外装'
        oldValue = newText;
        $('#form-label-category-exterior').trigger('change');
        return $return ? {id: newText, text: newText } : null;
      }
      return null;
    }
  })
  $('#form-label-category-exterior').on('select2:closing', function (e) {
    oldValue = ""
  });
});
```